# NA's appearing when subtracting one number from another in R

Tags: r

I have data in the following format in R:

```
Col1 Col2 
1    1
2    1
4    0
0    0
2    2
.    .
.    .
.    .
```

I'm using the following script to work out the percentage differences between Col1 & Col2 in each row.

```
temp <- matrix(numeric(),dim(data)[1],1)

for (i in 1:dim(data)[1])
{
 temp[i,1]<- ((data[i,1]-data[i,2)/data[i,1])*100
}
```

For some reason my output file (temp) has some NA's in it. They are occurring even when 0-0. Does anyone know why it isn't just producing a 0 as opposed to NA? Some sums of 0-0 are producing a 0 as opposed to NA so I can't see any real pattern.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks,

Comment: Why don't you simply use `Col2 - Col1`? Keep in mind that R is not Java or C++, and make use of the fact that all operations are vectorized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are making the classic division by zero error.  R reports this as `NaN` - not a number, which is correct.

```
x <-structure(list(
  Col1 = c(1L, 2L, 4L, 0L, 2L), Col2 = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L)), 
  .Names = c("Col1", "Col2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))

with(x, (Col2-Col1)/Col1)
[1]  0.0 -0.5 -1.0  NaN  0.0
```

---

One way to work around this is to use `ifelse` to return zero whenever `Col==0`:

```
with(x, ifelse(Col1==0, 0, (Col2-Col1)/Col1))
[1]  0.0 -0.5 -1.0  0.0  0.0
```

---

If you don't want to use `with`, then write your code like this (more verbose but identical):

```
ifelse(x$Col1==0, 0, (x$Col2-x$Col1)/x$Col1)
[1]  0.0 -0.5 -1.0  0.0  0.0
```

Comment: I see - I didn't notice the NaN as opposed to NA. So if I can be sure that all NA's should be 0's, then I can simply replace all of them with 0's.

Comment: Yes, but it would be better to write your code to avoid this type of `NaN` in the first place. If you simply replace all `NaN` with 0, then you might inadvertently be introducing other errors.

Comment: Ok - for other reasons I would like to keep the loop that I have, so how can I incorporate a fix like you've suggested into the code that I have provided?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not going to help you to write rubbish R code.

Comment: Well I haven't even used the with function before so it's a bit useless for me at the moment. Bit pointless throwing code into my script that I don't understand. A shame as you obviously have the know-how. Oh well!

Comment: OK, you don't need `with` in this case. I'll edit my answer to write this in the long-winded way.

Answer (score 1):

For those entries, you're dividing by zero:

```
(0 - 0) / 0
```

Mathematically, the result of such a division is [not defined](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_by_zero). To indicate this, R evaluates `0/0` as [`NaN`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN).

Here is a concise way to compute all percentags at once, returning zeroes for entries where both `Col1` and `Col2` are zero:

```
> data <- data.frame(Col1=c(1,2,4,0,2), Col2=c(1,1,0,0,2))
> pmax(100.0*(data$Col1-data$Col2)/data$Col1, 0, na.rm=T)
[1]   0  50 100   0   0
```

Comment: Getting close. You should use `is.nan` to test for `NaN`, instead of `is.na`

Comment: @Andrie: Why is that? `is.na()` tests for both.

Comment: Because my view on software development is that you should only test for the error that you know you have introduced, not other classes of errors as well. What about the case where you have existing NA values in your data, for example? Which is why an `ifelse` type solution to prevent the `NaN` values in the first place has to be a better solution. (In other words, prevent, rather than fix.)